# type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic in flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a API request in Flutter but i am getting following error as response

> type 'List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'Map<String, dynamic>'

I am trying to create first API and kindly let me know if the approach is fine

here is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Product {
  final int id;
  final String title, description;
  final String images;
  final List<Color> colors;
  final double price;
  final double rating;
  final bool isFavourite, isPopular;

  Product(
      {this.id,
      this.images,
      this.colors,
      this.title,
      this.price,
      this.rating,
      this.description,
      this.isFavourite,
      this.isPopular});
  factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Product(
      id: json['id'],
      images: json['images'],
      title: json['title'],
      price: json['price'],
      rating: json['rating'],
      description: json['description'],
    );
  }
}


Future<Product> fetchProd() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://test.com/sampleapi.php');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return Product.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.body));
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}

class ProdList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ProdListState createState() => _ProdListState();
}

class _ProdListState extends State<ProdList> {
  Future<Product> futureProdLists;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    futureProdLists = fetchProd();
  
  }

 

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(children: [
      Padding(
        padding:
            EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
        child: SectionTitle(title: "Popular Products", press: () {}),
      ),
      SizedBox(height: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
      SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: FutureBuilder<Product>(
          future: futureProdLists,
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            print(snapshot);
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return Text(snapshot.data.title);
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
```

Here is my sample API

```
[
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "images": "assets/images/ps4_console_white_1.png",
    "title": "Wireless Controller for PS4",
    "price": 25,
    "description": "description",
    "rating": 4.8,
    "rating (copy)": 4.8,
    "isFavourite": true,
    "isPopular": true
  },
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "images": "assets/images/ps4_console_white_1.png",
    "title": "Wireless Controller for PS4",
    "price": 25,
    "description": "description",
    "rating": 4.8,
    "rating (copy)": 4.8,
    "isFavourite": true,
    "isPopular": true
  },
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "images": "assets/images/ps4_console_white_1.png",
    "title": "Wireless Controller for PS4",
    "price": 25,
    "description": "description",
    "rating": 4.8,
    "rating (copy)": 4.8,
    "isFavourite": true,
    "isPopular": true
  },
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "images": "assets/images/ps4_console_white_1.png",
    "title": "Wireless Controller for PS4",
    "price": 25,
    "description": "description",
    "rating": 4.8,
    "rating (copy)": 4.8,
    "isFavourite": true,
    "isPopular": true
  },
  {
    "id": "0001",
    "images": "assets/images/ps4_console_white_1.png",
    "title": "Wireless Controller for PS4",
    "price": 25,
    "description": "description",
    "rating": 4.8,
    "rating (copy)": 4.8,
    "isFavourite": true,
    "isPopular": true
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The thing is your `api` response giving you an `json` array of product object and you are trying to convert the array to product object that is the problem.

Now you have to iterate the `json` array and convert each element to Product object and store them in a list.

Replace your `fetchProd` method with bellow code snippet.

```
Future<List<Product>> fetchProd() async {
  List<Product> prodList = [];

  final response = await http.get('https://test.com/sampleapi.php');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    var jsonList = jsonDecode(response.body);
    for(var prod in jsonList){
      prodList.add(Product.fromJson(prod));
    }
    return prodList;
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

Comment: A value of type 'List<Product>' can't be returned from function 'fetchProd' because it has a return type of 'Future<Product>'.dartreturn_of_invalid_type

Comment: As @Saiful Islam its API returns JSON array not json object so that is List not Map.

Comment: I updated the code so make a try now. @vellai durai

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Future<Product> fetchProd() async {
  final response = await http.get('https://test.com/sampleapi.php');

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    // If the server did return a 200 OK response,
    // then parse the JSON.
    return (response.body as List)
      .map((item) => Product.fromJson(item))
      .toList();
  } else {
    // If the server did not return a 200 OK response,
    // then throw an exception.
    throw Exception('Failed to load album');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This will work for sure.
`final Product product = productFromJson(jsonString);`

```
import 'dart:convert';

List<Product> productFromJson(String str) => List<Product>.from(json.decode(str).map((x) => Product.fromJson(x)));

String productToJson(List<Product> data) => json.encode(List<dynamic>.from(data.map((x) => x.toJson())));

class Product {
    Product({
        this.id,
        this.images,
        this.title,
        this.price,
        this.description,
        this.rating,
        this.ratingCopy,
        this.isFavourite,
        this.isPopular,
    });

    String id;
    String images;
    String title;
    int price;
    String description;
    double rating;
    double ratingCopy;
    bool isFavourite;
    bool isPopular;

    factory Product.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => Product(
        id: json["id"],
        images: json["images"],
        title: json["title"],
        price: json["price"],
        description: json["description"],
        rating: json["rating"].toDouble(),
        ratingCopy: json["rating (copy)"].toDouble(),
        isFavourite: json["isFavourite"],
        isPopular: json["isPopular"],
    );

    Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
        "id": id,
        "images": images,
        "title": title,
        "price": price,
        "description": description,
        "rating": rating,
        "rating (copy)": ratingCopy,
        "isFavourite": isFavourite,
        "isPopular": isPopular,
    };
}
```